# Encryption module uses high memory while running for large data

Tags: encryption, memory-leaks, .net-5, memorystream

We are trying to encrypt huge table data (3 million ), When we use the below encryption method it constantly makes a memory issue. When use 'using' keyword memory stream object should be disposed some period of time, What could be the other reason? When I disable the line***(var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, initializationVector)***;   // Does it make any problem             ), memory becomes stable .

.NET 5

```cs
internal class EncryptionServiceBase
    {

        protected byte[] Encrypt(byte[] decryptedData, byte[] key, byte[] initializationVector, Action<AesCryptoServiceProvider> setupDelegate)
        {
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(decryptedData, nameof(decryptedData));
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(key, nameof(key));
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(initializationVector, nameof(initializationVector));

            **using (var cryptoProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                setupDelegate(cryptoProvider);
                var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, initializationVector);**    // Does it make any problem             
                return GetCryptoTransformedData(decryptedData, encryptor);
            }
        }

        protected byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] key, byte[] initializationVector, Action<AesCryptoServiceProvider> setupDelegate)
        {
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(encryptedData, nameof(encryptedData));
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(key, nameof(key));
            Guard.IsNotNullOrEmpty(initializationVector, nameof(initializationVector));

            using (var cryptoProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                setupDelegate(cryptoProvider);
                var decryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(key, initializationVector);

                return GetCryptoTransformedData(encryptedData, decryptor);
            }
        }

        private byte[] GetCryptoTransformedData(byte[] data, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
       

    }
```

Comment: Don't encrypt the whole thing in one piece. Encrypt in smaller chunks, so you can assemble the whole thing on disk.

Comment: We are encrypting each row by row, not whole things ..

Comment: Where are you storing the encrypted rows? On disk or in memory? If in memory, you will need to copy the memory to disk every so often to reduce memory usage.

Comment: As I said, It takes rows one by one . After each iteration, it encrypts and inserts into another DB table as encrypted data.

Comment: I think this make problem : **using (var cryptoProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                setupDelegate(cryptoProvider);
                var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, initia